# Using a linked camera from another file

Tags: animation, camera, linked-data

SO I linked an animated camera from another file, however when i press Numb0 or ctrl+Numb0 the results are weird, basically from what i can tell it just like a centered camera looking face down.

Is there a way to use a linked animated camera from another file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work if......

I created a group out of only the camera in the linked file ("A").

In my new file ("B"), I linked in the group from ("A").

In the outliner, I expanded (drilled down into) the linked group.

Then on the child group object:

1. Right Clicked.
2. Select >> Link Group Object To Scene.
3. Selected the camera object in the 3D view.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

Comment: I think this is outdated in 3.1
I can't select the linked camera to make it main

Answer (score 0):

Your camera will appear like the image down there without the black mark and it is because it is not the active camera and in my case the active camera is the cube it self. When you press 'ctrl+numpad 0' it will make the active object as an active camera perspective.

[image]
To solve that:
- select your camera and then press 'ctrl+numpad 0'
or
- select the camera and follow the menu like the image down.

[image]